# how get entire retrieved tabled data into excel in jsp

Tags: java, excel, jsp, hssf

I'm using this code but only row of table data is entered into file.. .I'm using mysql database. connection is established in connection.jsp. tablename is login. using poi-2.5.1.jar file. this code is working without any error but how to get entire table data into excel sheet

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
         <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
                <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@pageimport="java.util.*,java.io.*,javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*"%>
         <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
         <%@include file="connection.jsp" %>
         <%@page import="  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*"%>
         <head>
            <meta httpequiv="ContentType"content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
                 <title>JSP Page</title>
             </head>
             <% response.setContentType("application/xls");
                response.setHeader("ContentDisposition","attachment;filename=File.xls"); %>
             <body>
                 <table>
                     <tr><th>CG</th><th>CD</th></tr>
                 <%
                 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String filename="C:/Users/sangu/Downloads/data.xls" ;
         HSSFWorkbook hwb=new HSSFWorkbook();
         HSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("sheet");

         HSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)0);
             ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from login ");
             while (res.next())
            {            
                     String cg = res.getString(1);
                 String cd = res.getString(3);
                 row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(cd);
         row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(cd);
         row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(cd);                
                 %>
                 <tr>
                 <td align="center"><%=cg%></td>
                 <td align="center"><%=cd%></td>
                 </tr>
                <%
         FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(filename);
         hwb.write(fileOut);
         fileOut.close();
         out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
                        hwb.write(response.getOutputStream()); }
                 %>
                 </table>
             </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: You are creating the FileOutputStream and closing it on every iteration of the while loop. Create the object before the loop starts and then close it after the loop is completely done.

Comment: thank you, but output is same sir. can you please suggest me the required editing in code or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know for sure but shouldn't be
`HSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)0);`
inside while loop? so it will create new row for every result?

EDIT:

```
                     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String filename="C:/Users/sangu/Downloads/data.xls" ;
     HSSFWorkbook hwb=new HSSFWorkbook();
     HSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("sheet");


         ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from login ");
         while (res.next())
        {        
             HSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)0);
             String cg = res.getString(1);
             String cd = res.getString(3);
             row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(cd);
     row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(cd);
     row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(cd);                
             %>
             <tr>
             <td align="center"><%=cg%></td>
             <td align="center"><%=cd%></td>
             </tr>
            <%
     FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(filename);
     hwb.write(fileOut);
     fileOut.close();
     out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
                    hwb.write(response.getOutputStream()); }
```